# Webographie in latex

Tags: texworks

I need to add bibliography to my report but the presentation that I get is not satisfied when I have url longer than 1 line (I dont want space between https and //);
[image]

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

...

\bibitem{maReference13}https://fr.ryte.com/wiki/PHP

\bibitem{maReference14}https://www.doc-etudiant.fr/Informatique/Programmation/Cours-Introduction-a-eclipse-130720.html

\bibitem{maReference15}https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Please provide a full MWE. Are you using andy special package for handling URLs?

Comment: No i'm not using any package

Comment: Perhaps you should (like the `url` package)? With insufficient information (e.g. MWE) we sadly can't help you properly.

Comment: The `url` or `xurl` package should be used as they provide methods for properly line breaking a URL. `url` has specific rules as to which type of chars to break at, `xurl` does not. Each will use a montype font by default, but this is configurable, se the packages respective manuals.